# Debug in add and delete methods in BinarySearchTree in java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Ok, so I'm implementing a DictionaryADT interface with a BinarySearchTree for a PhoneBook.
My files are working fine except for the add and delete of the BST.
I'm not allowed to add duplicate entries but my tree is adding duplicates and can't figure out, why.
Similarly in delete, my deleted entry was found in the testing file, so I guess the delete doesn't works at all!
Here are my methods: Any help is really appreciated.

```
public boolean add(K key, V value) {

    if (root == null)
        root = new Node<K, V>(key, value);
    else
        insert(key, value, root, null, false);
    currentSize++;
    modCounter++;
    return true;

}

private void insert(K k, V v, Node<K, V> n, Node<K, V> parent, boolean wasLeft)
{
    if (n == null) {
        if (wasLeft)
            parent.leftChild = new Node<K, V>(k, v);
        else
            parent.rightChild = new Node<K, V>(k, v);
    }
    else if (((Comparable<K>) k).compareTo((K) n.key) < 0)
        insert(k, v, n.leftChild, n, true);
    else
        insert(k, v, n.rightChild, n, false);
}
```

and here is my delete:

```
  public boolean delete(K key){
        if (!this.contains(key)) {
            return false;
    }

    Node<K, V> node = find(key, root, 0);
    Node<K,V> parent = remove(node, root);
    root=parent;
    currentSize--;
    modCounter++;

    return true;
}


private Node<K,V> remove( Node<K,V> node_to_delete, Node<K,V> start_node )
{
    if( start_node == null )
        return start_node;   
    if(((Comparable<K>)node_to_delete.key).compareTo( start_node.key ) < 0 )
        start_node.leftChild = remove( node_to_delete, start_node.leftChild );
    else if(((Comparable<K>)node_to_delete.key).compareTo( start_node.key ) > 0 )
        start_node.rightChild = remove( node_to_delete, start_node.rightChild );
    else if( start_node.leftChild != null && start_node.rightChild != null ) 
    {
        start_node.key = findMin( start_node.rightChild ).key;
        start_node.rightChild = remove( start_node, start_node.rightChild );
    }
    else
        start_node = ( start_node.leftChild != null ) ? start_node.leftChild : start_node.rightChild;
    return start_node;
}

private Node<K,V> findMin( Node<K,V> t )
{
    if( t == null )
        return null;
    else if( t.leftChild == null )
        return t;
    return findMin( t.leftChild );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check is incomplete in `insert`:

```
else if (((Comparable<K>) k).compareTo((K) n.key) < 0)
    insert(k, v, n.leftChild, n, true);
else
    insert(k, v, n.rightChild, n, false);
```

If the result of comparison equals 0, you've encountered the value that's already present in the tree, so from this point you should discard the new value.

The `insert` should be something like this:

```
private void insert(K k, V v, Node<K, V> n, Node<K, V> parent, boolean wasLeft)
{
    if (n == null) {
        if (wasLeft)
            parent.leftChild = new Node<K, V>(k, v);
        else
            parent.rightChild = new Node<K, V>(k, v);
    }
    else {
        int result = ((Comparable<K>) k).compareTo((K) n.key);
        if (result < 0)
            insert(k, v, n.leftChild, n, true);
        else if(result > 0)
            insert(k, v, n.rightChild, n, false);
        //else: discard the data, it's a duplicate! 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that correction, I'll try doing that.
Also, did you catch the mistake in my delete method? It doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Might be related to the duplicates that where added by `insert`. Start by fixing the `insert`.

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem to work because that gave me a null pointer exception in the Phonebook which was working before doing that.

What I see in my add method is, I'm increasing the size n modCounter without checking if I'm actually inserting anything, so I guess I need to use if else condition for that, which defines the result if I inserted anything or not. Now how do I do that, can't think of a way to code this logic... Please help.

Comment: Make the `insert` return `boolean` according to success/failure and increase the counters only for success

Answer (score 0):

ok, now my files run fine, no duplicates added and delete also works fine... But!! When I print the numbers from the phonebook, a BST should give them out in a particular sorted order, isn't it? Thats not happening with my case...

Here's what I added to my add method..

```
Node<K,V> newNode = new Node<K,V>(key,value);
    if(contains(key))
        return false;
```

I don't understand why my numbers(keys) are just random and not in any particular order.